# How to connect to DB2 database from iReport 3.7.5?

Tags: jasper-reports, db2, ireport

I am new to DB2 and have no idea on about DB2 drivers also. I have to connect to DB2 database using iReport and generate reports.

I tried to connect to DB2 database from iReport. I got error like:

> COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver class not found.

I have added `db2jcc.jar` and `db2jcc_license_cu.jar` and `db2java.jar` files in iReport classpath (tools--->classpath). I have also added `db2java.jar` file in ireport services under (Window menu) it is loading this class `COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver`. But iReport was unable to load this class.

Comment: May we see what you have tried? Have you set up a Jasper Server? What OS are you wanting to run the server on? Are you wanting to run reports programmatically (i.e. over the SOAP API) or just at the web interface? Or do you just want to run reports from iReport with no server? If the latter, have you got a DB2 server running to try making connections?

Comment: @SaisreeA please edit and update your question with what you have tried and what is the actual error.